# Can only send php mail() from single server user

Tags: php, email, lamp, vps, ubuntu-16.04

#### Current setup:

- Server is a **VPS** hosted with Digital Ocean
- Server is **Ubuntu 16.04**
- **LAMP** Setup

#### Problem:

I am trying to use the PHP `mail()` function to send form emails to users etc. I can not specify an account that is not a user such as *noreply@myserver.com* as I have been able to do before with shared servers (GoDaddy). PHP mail is enabled however only sends when I use my user@mydomain.com, here is the php I am using to test the email:

```php
<?php

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$header = "From: noreply@myserver.com";
$subject = "Test email";
$body = "Test Email,\n\nIt works!";
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}

?>
```

This works if I replace the from with my **user@myserver.com** if not, no email. I am sure there is a package or some .conf file I have not setup but I have searched and found nothing.

Thanks for your help,

Aidan

--- EDIT ---

latest mail.log output:

```html
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22978]: u7PMfWV7022978: to=myuser@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, sta$
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22983]: u7PMfXXJ022983: from=www-data, size=123, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfXXJ022983@mywebsite.io>, relay=www-data@localhost
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22984]: u7PMfXT3022984: from=<www-data@mywebsite.io>, size=330, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfXXJ022983@mywebsite.io>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22983]: u7PMfXXJ022983: to=myuser@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, sta$
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22988]: u7PMfXSp022988: from=www-data, size=123, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfXSp022988@mywebsite.io>, relay=www-data@localhost
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22989]: u7PMfXRe022989: from=<www-data@mywebsite.io>, size=330, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfXSp022988@mywebsite.io>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22988]: u7PMfXSp022988: to=myuser@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, sta$
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22981]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22986]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22993]: u7PMfXuL022993: from=www-data, size=123, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfXuL022993@mywebsite.io>, relay=www-data@localhost
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22991]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22994]: u7PMfXjR022994: from=<www-data@mywebsite.io>, size=330, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfXuL022993@mywebsite.io>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22993]: u7PMfXuL022993: to=myuser@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, sta$
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22991]: u7PMfXRe022989: to=<myuser@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mywebsite.io> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120330, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. $
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22986]: u7PMfXT3022984: to=<myuser@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mywebsite.io> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120330, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. $
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22998]: u7PMfXfL022998: from=www-data, size=123, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfXfL022998@mywebsite.io>, relay=www-data@localhost
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22996]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sm-mta[22999]: u7PMfXFp022999: from=<www-data@mywebsite.io>, size=330, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfXfL022998@mywebsite.io>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 25 22:41:33 mywebsite sendmail[22998]: u7PMfXfL022998: to=myuser@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, sta$
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[22981]: u7PMfWXO022979: to=<myuser@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mywebsite.io> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120330, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. $
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23001]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[22996]: u7PMfXjR022994: to=<myuser@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mywebsite.io> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120330, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. $
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sendmail[23003]: u7PMfY9M023003: from=www-data, size=123, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfY9M023003@mywebsite.io>, relay=www-data@localhost
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23001]: u7PMfXFp022999: to=<myuser@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mywebsite.io> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120330, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. $
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23004]: u7PMfYXr023004: from=<www-data@mywebsite.io>, size=330, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfY9M023003@mywebsite.io>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sendmail[23003]: u7PMfY9M023003: to=myuser@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, sta$
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sendmail[23008]: u7PMfYjs023008: from=www-data, size=123, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfYjs023008@mywebsite.io>, relay=www-data@localhost
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23009]: u7PMfYPG023009: from=<www-data@mywebsite.io>, size=330, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfYjs023008@mywebsite.io>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sendmail[23008]: u7PMfYjs023008: to=myuser@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, sta$
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23006]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sendmail[23013]: u7PMfYZj023013: from=www-data, size=123, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfYZj023013@mywebsite.io>, relay=www-data@localhost
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23011]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23014]: u7PMfY77023014: from=<www-data@mywebsite.io>, size=330, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201608252241.u7PMfYZj023013@mywebsite.io>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sendmail[23013]: u7PMfYZj023013: to=myuser@gmail.com, ctladdr=www-data (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30123, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, sta$
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23006]: u7PMfYXr023004: to=<myuser@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mywebsite.io> (33/33), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=120330, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. $
Aug 25 22:41:34 mywebsite sm-mta[23016]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1.2, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256, bits=128/128
Aug 25 22:41:35 mywebsite sm-mta[23011]: u7PMfYPG023009: to=<myuser@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mywebsite.io> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120330, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. $
Aug 25 22:41:35 mywebsite sm-mta[23016]: u7PMfY77023014: to=<myuser@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<www-data@mywebsite.io> (33/33), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120330, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. $
```

Comment: you shouldn't be sending mail with fake headers.

Comment: @Dagon It is not for nefarious uses it is for legal website use.

Comment: and that's what all the the spammers say, so many MTA check.

Comment: @Dagon Thank you for your input, this would be pointing to my own VPS. eg: noreply@myservernotyours.com

Comment: ah ok, should work, your on a vps, so go look at the mail server logs

Comment: @Dagon I don't know if that helps but there is the log, I did install postfix before from a Digital Ocean tutorial but it didnt solve the issue so I flushed it. thanks

Comment: post logs. looks like its not your end, gmail probably just thinks it spam